# Чем отличается композиция от наследования?

Tags: java, наследование

Объясните по-человечески, желательно на примере, в чём заключается разница между композицией и наследованием? Читаю Философия Java Эккеля, застрял на этой теме, объясняется все вроде бы хорошо, но я не понял.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как и всем разработчикам, мне часто приходилось читать и слышать утверждение, что «композиция всегда лучше наследования». Наверное, даже слишком часто. Однако я не склонен принимать что-либо на веру, поэтому давайте разберёмся, так ли это.

Итак, какие же преимущества есть у композиции перед наследованием?

1. Нет конфликта имён, возможного при наследовании.
2. Возможность смены агрегируемого объекта в runtime.
3. Полная замена агрегируемого объекта в классах, производных от класса, включающего агрегируемый объект.

В последних двух случаях очень желательно, чтобы сменяемые агрегируемые объекты имели общий интерфейс. А в третьем – чтобы метод, возвращающий такой объект, был виртуальным.

Если рассматривать, например, C#, не поддерживающий множественное наследование, но позволяющий наследовать от множества интерфейсов и создавать методы расширения для этих интерфейсов, то можно выделить ещё два плюса (речь в данном случае может идти только о поведениях (алгоритмах) в рамках паттерна «Стратегия»):
4. Агрегируемое поведение (алгоритм) может включать в себя другие объекты. Что в частности позволяет переиспользовать посредством агрегации другое поведение.
5. При агрегации есть возможность скрыть определённую часть реализации, а также исходные параметры, необходимые поведению, посредством передачи их через конструктор (при наследовании поведению придётся запрашивать их через методы/свойства собственного интерфейса).

Но как же минусы? Неужели их нет?

1. Итак, если нам необходима возможность смены поведения извне, то композиция, по сравнению с наследованием, имеет принципиально другой тип отношений между объектом поведения и объектом, его использующим. Если при наследовании от абстрактного поведения мы имеем отношение 1:1, то при агрегации и возможности установки поведения извне мы получаем отношение 1:many. Т.е. один и тот же объект поведения может использоваться несколькими объектами-владельцами. Это порождает проблемы с общим для нескольких таких объектов-владельцев состоянием поведения.

Разрешить эту ситуацию можно, запретив установку поведения извне или доверив его, например, generic-методу:
void SetBehavior()
запретив тем самым создание поведения кем-либо, кроме объекта-владельца. Однако мы не можем запретить использовать поведение «где-то ещё». В языках без сборщика мусора (GC) это порождает понятные проблемы. Конечно, в таких языках можно неправомерно обратиться по ссылке и на сам объект-владелец, но, раздавая отделённые объекты поведения направо и налево, мы получаем в разы больше шансов получить exception.

2. Агрегация (и это, пожалуй, главный нюанс) отличается от наследования в первую очередь тем, что агрегируемый объект не является объектом-владельцем и не содержит информации о нём. Нередки ситуации, когда коду, взаимодействующему с поведением, необходим и сам объект-владелец (например, для получения информации о том, какими ещё поведениями он обладает).

В таком случае, нам придётся или передавать в такой код нетипизированный объект (как object или void*), или создавать дополнительный интерфейс для объекта-владельца (некий IBehaviorOwner), или хранить в поведении циклическую ссылку на объект-владелец. Понятно, что каждый из этих вариантов имеет свои минусы и ещё больше усложняет код. Более того, различные типы поведений могут зависеть друг от друга (и в это вполне допустимо, особенно если они находятся в некоем закрытом самодостаточном модуле).

3. Ну и последний минус — это конечно же производительность. Если объектов-владельцев достаточно много, то создание и уничтожение вместо одного объекта двух или более может не остаться незамеченным.

Получается, что утверждение «композиция всегда лучше наследования» в ряде случаев спорно и не должно являться догмой. Особенно это касается языков, позволяющих множественное наследование и не имеющих GC. Если в какой-либо ситуации перечисленные выше плюсы не важны, и заранее известно, что при работе с определёнными типами у вас не будет возможности их использовать, стоит всё-таки рассмотреть вариант наследования.

Comment: Оригинал, если что: https://habr.com/post/177447/

Comment: Окей, спасибо за ответ. То есть как я понял, наследование имеет отношение IS-A, а композиция - HAS-A. Например, самолёт наследует свойствв транспорта. Это наследование. Но самолет имеет, например, крыло. Это уже композиция. Верно?

Comment: Из абстрактного на первый взгляд транспорта тоже можно сделать самолет с помощью композиции.